# phpmailer SMTP with STARTTLS encryption

Tags: encryption, smtp, composer-php, phpmailer, starttls

would anyone know if it is possible to run ***phpmailer with STARTTLS encryption***?

The story: an online order form that sends the output to both the site visitor and site owner. The goal is that the visitor receives an email from ***orders@ownerdomain.com***, while the site owner receives an email from ***visitor@somedomain.com*** (the address that the visitor has filled i the online form).

I have the phpmailer running fine with my Gmail account, using TLS on port 587. I would, however, like to use mailbox provided along with the hosting (so that the from/replyTo looks professional, no freemail). Unfortunately, the hosting provider does not provide TLS - in their knowledgebase they only mention STARTTLS. I tried all combinations of SSL, TLS and STARTTLS for encryption and 465 and 587 for ports with no success.

Would anyone know if STARTTLS is somehow achievable, please?

---

My plan B would was to use the Gmail SMTP credentials and then tinker with ***addReplyTo***, ***setFrom*** and ***addAddress*** in the phpmailer SMTP settings. I tried but if I use...

```
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['customeremail'], $_POST['customername']);
```

...the ***from*** email address the site owner receives is that of my Google email - I understand this may be some Google email spoofing protection, which just doesn`t allow the SMTP to send an email with the ***From address*** taken from the form. - please see the attached ![Thunderbird screen( image: imgur.com/a/1f6vY).

Can this be possibly overridden?

I mean, with that plan B solution, I can grant Google access to send emails on behalf of `orders@ownerdomain.com`, that`s all fine, it will then mimick the professional domain address. But I cannot do the same for the visitor address (taken from the form), that makes sense, right?

Thanks a bunch in advance...

Comment: Sorry, hereby the image: https://imgur.com/a/1f6vY

Comment: I mean, with that plan B solution, I can grant Google acccess to send emails on behalf of orders@ownerdomain.com, that`s all fine, it will then mimick the professional domain address. But I cannot do the same for the visitor address (taken from the form), that makes sense, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHPMailer does TLS encryption by default. Look at the `SMTPSecure` property for more details.

Gmail does indeed prevent you from setting arbitrary from addresses, though you can pre-set aliases in your account. This is mentioned in the PHPMailer docs and has been covered many times on here.

Comment: Thanks, but I am essentially having difficulties undersanding the difference between TLS and STARTTLS. Or SSL/TLS. I am set with "SMTPAuth = true;", but need to make STARTTLS work. Will try googling deeper, nevertheless.

Comment: TLS is simply the newer (since 1998!) name for SSL. STARTTLS is a mechanism for an unencrypted connection to start using encryption. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;` and you will see what's happening. This is all covered in the troubleshooting guide that PHPMailer errors provide links to. Base your code on the gmail example provided with PHPMailer.